# Radio Buttons with JavaScript in a Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have this JavaScript code that I am using for form validation and I am trying to put two radio buttons into and have them validate the same way that the rest of the form is but am not getting it to work. My html for the buttons is:

```
<label class="required" for="buttons">How May I Contact You:</label><br/>
    <input id="radio" type="radio0" name="contact" value="email">Email<br>
    <input id="radio" type="radio1" name="contact" value="no contact">No Contact<br>
    <span id="radio_validation" class="error"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email" onclick="validate()" value="Check"/>
```

This is the JavaScript that I am using. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I do not know much about JavaScript yet.

```
function validateForm() {
  var valid = 1;
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var email_validation = document.getElementById("email_validation");
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
  var name_validation = document.getElementById("name_validation");
  var message_validation = document.getElementById("message_validation");
  var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

  if (name.value === "") {
    valid = 0;
    name_validation.innerHTML = "Field Required";
    name_validation.style.display = "block";
    name_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
  } else {
    name_validation.style.display = "none";
    name_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";

  }

  if (message.value === "") {
    valid = 0;
    message_validation.innerHTML = "Field Required";
    message_validation.style.display = "block";
    message_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
  } else {
    message_validation.style.display = "none";
    message_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }

  if (email.value === "") {
    valid = 0;
    email_validation.innerHTML = "Field Required";
    email_validation.style.display = "block";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
  } else {
    email_validation.style.display = "none";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }

  if(!filter.test(email.value)) {
    valid = 0;
    email_validation.innerHTML = "Invalid email address";
    email_validation.style.display = "block";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#FFDFDF";
  } else {
    email_validation.style.display = "none";
    email_validation.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
  }
  if (!valid)
    return false;
}
```

Comment: FYI IDs **must** be unique. I also don't see where you attempt to validate your radio buttons.

Comment: [-1 not enough jQuery](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif). There's actually many HTML5 features that help in validating, like setting `required` and `type = "email"` in an input, so you might want to check that and not writing so much javascript (;

Comment: I took them out after hours of making a hug mess of things. Sorry I had them changed at one point..sorry been up all night working on this.

Comment: Please put your code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Personally I think that radio button groups should *always* have a "checked" button. That way it's kind-of impossible for a user to submit the form without a checked button (unless they sabotage their own form deliberately).

Comment: yes..i would much prefer to use html5 for this..that is what i am good  at..I have to use javascript for this though

Comment: Any particular reason? Support for legacy browsers?

Comment: Reason for JavaScript?  College class. I am a designer..not much of a scripter

Comment: this class is about 8 years behind but I have to do it

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/QJ9Y9/

Comment: Wrong jsfiddle or wrong question... that jsfiddle is about exploding elements

Comment: ignore that on the right. i don't know how to get rid of it..do you want all the code for the whole page in it or just the part for this question?

Comment: sorry i don't know how to jsfiddle..